How to insert values into an object using Jquery
Sorry for this silly question, newbie here.
I'm trying to do a testing and I want to insert the element name and ALT text values into var tagged ={} object.
var $img = $('#gallery img');
var tagged = {};
$img.each(function(el, val) {
   
    tagged[el] = val  <-----this is the part where I'm lost
})
console.log("tagged result : ", tagged);

My goal is to have this result like: {img, picture1, img, picture2}

The object can only have ONE item with the same key. So use a different key than the tagname - I used the ID and have each image have a different ID


var $img = $('#gallery img');
var tagged = {};
$img.each(function(idx, el) {
  tagged[el.id] = {[el.tagName]:el.alt}; 
})
console.log("tagged result : ", tagged);

// or

tagged = []
$img.each(function(idx, el) {
  tagged.push({[el.id]:el.alt}); 
})
console.log("tagged result : ", tagged);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
  <img id="img1" src="test1.jpg" alt="img alt 1" />
  <img id="img2" src="test2.jpg" alt="img alt 2" />
  <img id="img3" src="test3.jpg" alt="img alt 3" />
 </div>




thanks for your reply. i tried your suggestion, and the return value is exactly what i needed.
However, it did not loop through the other tags.
result was : {img: picture1}
my goal is to loop through each. May I know how can i achieve this?

by the way, i can easily get my desired output using .push method, however, I need the values to be in object not array.

The object can only have ONE item with the same key. So use a different key than the tagname - I used the ID and have each image have a different ID

thanks so much for your help! that worked! I appreciate your help and fast response!

You intend to create an object of key-value pairs, where the value is the image element. It's unclear to me what the keys should be, but basically you can use any key you want as you have a solid idea of what the end-result you want to achieve is. Your original code created an index for the images and that index was being used as the key. In my example the images have a title each and I use it as the key.


$(function() {
    var $img = $('#gallery img'); var tagged = {};

    $img.each(function(el, val) {
   
        tagged[this.title] = val;
    })
    console.log("tagged result : ", tagged);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
    <img title="forest from afar" src="https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5eb18e42fc043ed5d9779733/16:9/w_1920%2Cc_limit/BlackForest-Germany-GettyImages-147180370.jpg">
    <img title="rolling on the river" src="https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/592debf3a67ebe23dff78b2f/master/w_1920%2Cc_limit/amazon-rainforest-GettyImages-137578327.jpg">
</div>



Images were taken from here: https://www.cntraveler.com/gallery/the-most-beautiful-forests-in-the-world
EDIT
You cannot make an object to be your key, because it will be stringified and it will not operate as a key for you:


let o1 = {a: '1', b: '2'}
let o2 = {c: '3', d: '4'}

console.log({
    [o1]: 'something',
    [o2]: 'something else'
});




sorry if my question was not clear. I'm trying to make img element to appear in tagged object and the alt text values
{img as element, picture1 as the ALT text}
img = element tag
picture1 = alt value
I tried your suggestion and it's almost there. the result i got was {picture1: img: picture2, img) and i could not make
it like {img: picture1, img: picture 2}

@JayteeCollins you will not be able to use objects as another object's keys. Can you explain why you need this object? Maybe then we could address your issue in a better manner.
